# How to convert / cast long to String?

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, long-integer

I just created sample BB app, which can allow to choose the date.

```
DateField curDateFld = new DateField("Choose Date: ",
  System.currentTimeMillis(), DateField.DATE | DateField.FIELD_LEFT);
```

After choosing the date, I need to convert that long value to String, so that I can easily store the date value somewhere in database.
I am new to Java and Blackberry development.

```
long date = curDateFld.getDate();
```

How should I convert this long value to String? Also I want to convert back to long from String. I think for that I can use `long l = Long.parseLong("myStr");`?

Answer (score 410):

See the [reference documentation for the String class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html): `String s = String.valueOf(date);`

If your Long might be null and you don't want to get a 4-letter `"null"` string, you might use [`Objects.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), like: `String s = Objects.toString(date, null);`

---

EDIT:

You reverse it using `Long l = Long.valueOf(s);` but in this direction you need to catch `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Note that `Long.valueOf(String)` returns a `Long`. If you want a `long`, use `Long.parseLong(String)`.

Comment: What's the differente between this way, or just concat like this: ("" + longAttr) ?

Comment: @MarceloAssis.. concat is about 2x slower. If performance matters in you application.

Comment: Nice, but note that ``java.util.Objects`` is only available since Java 7.

Comment: Before Java 7, you could also use Commons Lang's ``ObjectUtils.toString(Object,String)`` which is equivalent. -> https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html#toString(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 231):

```
String strLong = Long.toString(longNumber);
```

Simple and works fine :-)

Comment: For general type conversion outside the `Date` context this is the recommended practise to convert `Long` to `String`.

Comment: Works fine with primitive type (long), but may throw NPE with Object type (Long), even with autoboxing.

Answer (score 108):

## `Long.toString()`

This should work:

```
long myLong = 1234567890123L;
String myString = Long.toString(myLong);
```

Comment: Is there any difference to `String.valueOf(myLong)`?

Comment: @membersound they're the same. Basically String.valueOf(long) calls Long.toString()

Comment: @Nero I wouldn't call the same because String.valueOf() will return "null" in case of null, while Long.toString() will cause NullPointerException

Answer (score 20):

very simple,
just concatenate the long to a string.

```
long date = curDateFld.getDate(); 
String str = ""+date;
```

Answer (score 10):

1.

```
long date = curDateFld.getDate();
//convert long to string
String str = String.valueOf(date);

//convert string to long
date = Long.valueOf(str);
```

2.

```
 //convert long to string just concat long with empty string
 String str = ""+date;
//convert string to long

date = Long.valueOf(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String logStringVal= date+"";
```

Can convert the long into string object, cool shortcut for converting into string...but use of `String.valueOf(date);` is advisable

Comment: I thought `String.valueOf` was the preferred approach but I noticed that just calls `Long.toString` so maybe that's the simpler way.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
String strLong = Long.toString(longNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String longString = new String(""+long);
```

or

```
String longString = new Long(datelong).toString();
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14830916)

Comment: @KrupalShah A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)