# How to store a long/double/int inside of a String in Java

Tags: java, string, long-integer

So let's have I have the long `12321431` , how would I store that as a String variable inside of Java?

Or let's say 10.15, how would I store it inside a String?

I'm still a newbie at this and I need to do this for file-io purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java:Convert / Cast long to String ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854924/javaconvert-cast-long-to-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert and Dici mentioned, you can use either of the two variations below:

```
num.toString(); // string representation

String.valueOf(num); // calls toString
```

`String.valueOf` calls the `toString` method of an object. It is now convention to cast using static methods rather than instance methods derived from the most basic Object class. I felt like the underlying code and reasoning was lacking in the other responses.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `String.valueOf` to convert it into a String.

Answer (score 0):

String strLong = Long.toString(longNumber);

Comment: `String.valueOf` calls the `toString` method of an object. It is now convention to cast using static methods rather than instance methods derived from the most basic Object class.